# Setting an icon to a marker in a Map from an image URL

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I want to set an icon, to **marker** in **Map**, from a **URL**. I saw many solutions, but all are showing how to set icon from our drawable folder. Here I want something different, I have a profile image URL and I need to set that image as an icon to my marker. Please suggest me a solution to this. 
Her is my code :

```
private void setUpCurrentMarker(LatLng latLng) {
    mMap.clear();
    if (!isUp)
        onSlideViewButtonClick(addressView);
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}
```

Comment: have you tried to pass image url .icon("Image url from Json Response")..?

Comment: @pawankasar no, I don't understand what you meant

Comment: I mean try to pass your image url to .icon("Image url");  method after .title()

Comment: @pawankasar no, that .icon method only accepts Bitmap type as parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("Your Image Url");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```

@Rahul Surendram Please try above solution hope it will help you...!

Comment: let me check it sir